# Determining custom Yolov4 output layer shape for 2 classes

Tags: ml.net, darknet, onnx, yolov4

I've recently trained a darknet yolov4 model to detect 2 objects, converted it to tensorflow and then onnx using the following tutorial.

https://github.com/onnx/models/blob/master/vision/object_detection_segmentation/yolov4/dependencies/Conversion.ipynb

I ended up with a model with the following input and output layer dimensions
[image]

How can I determine the shape of the three output layers that have the unknown numbers?
I need them so I can use the model in ML.Net.

Answer (score 0):

This is easy:

unk__2241 is batch size, so its unknown for now.

After CSPDarknet53, your output shape is (unk_2241,13,13,512) as reduce factor is 32. Then after SPP you have (unk_2241, 13, 13, 2048) with kernel size = [1,3,5,13].

You have 3 heads for detecting large, medium and small objects on image and 3 anchors per each of size of object. In this 3 heads yolo uses 3 feature maps which comes from modified PANet and this feature maps are (unk_2241,52,52,256), (unk_2241,26,26,512), (unk_2241,13,13,1024) as reduce factor is 8, 16, 32.

Then before each yolo layer, there is convolution for making final feature map and its shape is (unk_2241, 52, 52, 21), (unk_2241, 26, 26, 21) , (unk_2241, 13, 13, 21), and kernel shape is (256, (class number + coords of bbox + confidence)*anchor number for each size, 1, 1) ->(256, 21, 1, 1), (512, 21, 1, 1), (1024, 21, 1, 1).

And in yolo head you will have (unk_2241, 52, 52, 3, 7), (unk_2241, 26, 26, 3, 7), (unk_2241, 13, 13, 3, 7), where yolo head is dividing last axis of input by number of anchor, and number of class + coords of bbox + confidence.

As the result:

1. unk__2241 = unk__2242 = unk__2245 = unk__2248 -> They all batch sizes.
2. YOLO head output shapes: (unk_2242, 52, 52, 3, 7), (unk_2245, 26, 26, 3, 7), (unk_2248, 13, 13, 3, 7).
3. Batch size could be size of all dataset.

Comment: quick tip : put the codes in code samples to make it easier to read

Comment: Thanks for tip, but there's no code, only matrices shapes)

Comment: well yeah you can put them in code samples too